# PowerShell Profile does not get applied

Tags: powershell

I have opened PowerShell Profile by
$ notepad $PROFILE

And add these to the top of the file

```
Import-Module posh-git
Import-Module oh-my-posh 
Set-PoshPrompt -Theme powerlevel10k_lean
```

But when I open a new PowerShell, my prompt theme does not get applied.

The file of $profile is at
`C:\Users\hwang\OneDrive - Microsoft\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

output of  `$PROFILE | Format-List * -Force` is

```
AllUsersAllHosts       : C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost    : C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
CurrentUserAllHosts    : C:\Users\hwang\OneDrive - Microsoft\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost : C:\Users\hwang\OneDrive - Microsoft\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
Length                 : 90
```

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: It is under `C:\Users\hwang\OneDrive - Microsoft\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Comment: Have you tried running `Add-PoshGitToProfile`?  Where is the profile file located exactly that you edited? You can display the location of the profile you modified, by running `$profile`, in a PowerShell prompt.  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting commentary.  Make sure `$profile` matches the file you just provided, and [edit] your question, to include that vital necessary information.

Comment: In order to to provide the correct command, to get additional information, I need the output of `$PROFILE | Format-List * -Force`

Comment: Instead of running `Add-PostGitToProfile` you should run `Add-PoshGitToProfile -AllUsers -AllHosts` then post the contents of your `CurrentUserAllHosts` profile file.  You will want to close all PowerShell prompts after you run the command.  Before you run the command, in the prompt that does not work, you will want to run `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` and provide that information.  *The reason "it's not working" is your PowerShell environment is not using the correct profile.*

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, resolved it by changing settings:
In Settings > Startup > Default profile
Choose PowerShell, save.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).